# How can I delete the files directory when I download a complete page in Firefox?

Tags: windows-7, firefox

Using Firefox 19 on Windows 7 I downloaded a webpage using "Save Page As" and saved as "Web Page, complete".  It downloads both the html and a folder containing the images, css, and js.  The folder and the html are siblings in the directory hierarchy.  If I delete or move either the html or files folder the other is deleted or moved along with it.

I realize I just get the html by choosing "Web Page, HTML only" when saving but I'm still baffled as to how this works as I've never seen files linked in this way.  Is this a feature in Windows 7?  How would one go about deleting one without the other if they wanted to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [Connected Files](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/252721) feature of 2000 and XP and later version of Windows. The rules are pretty simple, if you make a change to an .htm or .html file, and there is a folder in the same directory with the same name, the action will be carried out on it as well.

You can rename either the folder or the html file first, and you will be warned you are disconnecting the html and folder.  After this, you can delete either the folder or file.

To turn off this behaviour, you can create this registry key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer

Value: NoFileFolderConnection
Value Type: REG_DWORD
Value Data: 1
```

Comment: You can also go to "Folder Options" from any Explorer window; on the View tab, there's a setting titled "Managing pairs of Web pages and folders".  (That's what it's called on Windows 8; the same setting existed in XP, Vista and 7, but the title might have been a bit different.)

Comment: @MT_Head: The "Managing pairs of Web pages and folders" UI setting in Explorer is not present by default in any version of Windows AFAIK. It's added by Office, although I'm not exactly sure which component adds it, since I performed custom installs of Office 2010 on two PCs and only one has that setting.

Comment: @Karan - Well, I'll be dipped!  Office is always one of the first things I install on a new machine, so it's been a very long time since I've worked with a Windows box without it.  (I keep trying to switch to LibreOffice, but formatting/macro compatibility keeps bringing me back.)  It never even crossed my mind that that was an add-on.